# ITerm: Is there a way to reprint output of previous command without running it?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, iterm2, iterm

Of course, we can feed the output of any command to a file. Using `command > /tmp/filename`

Or even better use `command |  tee /tmp/filename`  to have the standard output be fed onto the terminal as well as the file name.

However, If I just executed `command` is there a way for ITerm to reprint the output that `command` already fed to console without re-running the command (example use case: command is not idempotent and I want to `grep` something without having to touch the mouse)

Comment: To me, it is not clear what exactly you want to do here. Maybe something like `echo !!`? But I don't see any purpose for this.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the `script` command, which records your input + the output your commands generate.

To use it, just run `script` at the beginning, before you start any execution, and this will throw you in a new shell. which gets recorded in a file called `typescript` in your HOME folder.

Once you are done, you can `exit`, and then have all of the input + output in that `typescript` log file.

Comment: I like this idea! However, this sounds like it would be in a new shell each time (my aliases would not be  available in new shell). I wonder if its possible to do under the same shell, my mind is a bit burned by from my day work right now hence idea is not fully popping up.

Comment: If you have your aliases in your `.bashrc` file, they will be loaded with every new shell